# Tutorial on PR2 simulation in Electric or Fuerte?

Tags: ros, simulation, pr2-simulator, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

does someone have experience with running advanced PR2 simulation ([pr2_simulator](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator)), i.e. door opening or pick and place, using Electric or Fuerte? The [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials) ends with Diamondback. What I am looking for is similar tutorial but for Electric or Fuerte.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35011/tutorial-on-pr2-simulation-in-electric-or-fuerte?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial here works with Fuerte using the ros-fuerete-pr2 Ubuntu packages
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/BasicPR2Controls

Assuming you have set up the ROS environment, e.g.

```
  source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
```

Then running the following commands should bring up a simulation in an
empty world.

```
  export ROBOT=sim
  roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

Then you can start keyboard teleop to drive it around

```
  roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) with karma: 544 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-05-28**:
Yeah, I know about this one, however I'm interested in more complicated systems i.e. door opening or pick and place tutorials. I also tried them on diamondback, but the packages which are used in the tutorial are not available.